# Problema ao consumir dados da API e transferir um SRC para o ID

Tags: javascript, html, json

Eu tenho o seguinte código HTML:

```
<main>
  <blockquote class="blockquote text-center">Últimos produtos</blockquote>

  <!-- <INICIO CARDS> -->
  <div class="primeira-card">
    <div class="card-deck">
      <div class="card bg-dark">
        <img id="imagem-produto" class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 id="nome-do-produto" class="card-title"></h5>
          <p id="valor-do-produto" class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bg-dark">
        <img id="imagem-produto" class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 id="nome-do-produto" class="card-title"></h5>
          <p id="valor-do-produto" class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="card bg-dark">
        <img id="imagem-produto" class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="Card image cap">            
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 id="nome-do-produto" class="card-title"></h5>
          <p id="valor-do-produto" class="card-text"></p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="segunda-card">
      <div class="card-deck">
        <div class="card bg-dark">
        <img id="imagem-produto" class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 id="nome-do-produto" class="card-title"></h5>
            <p id="valor-do-produto" class="card-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-dark">
          <img id="imagem-produto" class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 id="nome-do-produto" class="card-title"></h5>
            <p id="valor-do-produto" class="card-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="card bg-dark">
          <img id="imagem-produto" class="img-responsive" src="#" alt="Card image cap">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 id="nome-do-produto" class="card-title"></h5>
            <p id="valor-do-produto" class="card-text"></p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <!-- <FIM CARDS> -->
</main>
```

Porém sempre quando faço a requisição dos itens de imagens do [products.json](https://thaleshenrique38.000webhostapp.com/products.json) ele não carrega nenhuma.

Alguém poderia me ajudar acredito que seja algum erro na própria sintaxe do Javascript.

Estou consumindo ele com o seguinte código:

```
const url = 'https://thaleshenrique38.000webhostapp.com/products.json';

function readJson() {
 fetch(url)
 .then(response => {
  if (!response.ok) {
   throw new Error("Erro HTTP: " + response.status);
  }
  return response.json();
 })
 .then(json => {
  this.response = json;
  document.getElementById('nome-do-produto').innerHTML = json[0].name;
  document.getElementById('valor-do-produto').innerHTML = json[0].Value;
  document.getElementById('imagem-produto').src = json[0].images.imageUrl
 })
 .catch(function () {
  this.dataError = true;
 })
}

readJson();
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço desde já.

CODEPEN: https://codepen.io/thales-henrique/pen/JzxXQQ

Comment: Adicione o código completo na pergunta, inclusive o HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O retorno do `fetch` fica armazenada na variável `json`:

```
.then(json => {
      ↑↑↑
```

Logo, em vez de `response.data.name`, deveria ser `json.name`. Porém, como o retorno é um array de objetos, logo apenas `json.name` daria *undefined*. Então você precisaria de índices, como por exemplo: `json[0].name`, `json[1].name` até o tamanho da array -1.

O que você deveria fazer era usar um laço `for` para percorrer todos os objetos da array, só que surge outro problema: como você está usando id's para enviar um `innerHTML`, não vai funcionar, porque um `id` deve ser único na página.

O `for` você poderia fazer assim:

```
for(var item of json){
   console.log(item);
}
```

Onde `item` é cada objeto da array. Logo, para pegar, por exemplo, o valor da chave `name`, você faz assim:

```
for(var item of json){
   console.log(item.name);
}
```

Comment: Consegui utilizar porém o for eu não entendi direito me desculpe!

Comment: O for vai percorrer cada objeto da array, onde "item" é cada objeto.

Comment: Entendi, mas no caso sabe o porque não estou conseguindo acessar as imagens; Seria alguma sintaxe incorreta?

Comment: As imagens é uma substância array